# What is the right way of passing array between scopes using two-way data binding in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assuming that there is an angular custom directive which uses an isolated scope for **array** object with **two-way** binding:

```
// scope values
this.scope = {
  myArray: '='
};
```

So, now if I will add objects to the array everything will work like a charm:

```
myArray.push(item); // array in the parent scope will be updated
```

However, when I will try to remove object from array via **[slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)** method it will not work - array will remain to be the same:

```
myArray.slice(itemIndex, 1); // ERROR: array will remain to be the same - item will not be deleted
```

Basically, slice creates a new array object which, as I understand, is prohibited by angular. So, the question is - what is the right way of passing array between scopes via two-way data binding with an ability of adding / removing objects ?

EDIT: many thanks to @ryanyuyu for the correct answer and his patience in explaining. In a nutshell:

- the problem has nothing in common with Angular and coupled with vanilla JavaScript API.
- read documentation meticulously because sometimes one character really matters ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Description) for `Array.slice`:

> `slice` does not alter. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array.

Also of note, the first argument is the starting index, and the second argument is the ending index.  To actually change your scope variable, you need to assign the return value like so:

```
myArray = myArray.slice(itemIndex, itemIndex+1);
```

---

More likely, you are looking to directly manipulate your array. Use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (that's splice with a **p**) to remove elements from the array.

```
myArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, solution with reassigning array does not work. Could you please clarify why do you use (itemIndex, itemIndex+1) - this does not look valid for item removal?

Comment: `slice` doesn't actually remove any elements.  It returns a subarray from the parent array.  The syntax in the documentation is `array.slice(startIndex, endIndex)`.  So if you only want to pull a single element, you have to start at an index and pull until the end index one greater that the start.  `splice` actually mutates the array.

Comment: yeah, I understand that it returns new array which is basically a sub array of initial one. So, for removing element from array one need to use the following syntax "myArray.slice(itemIndex, 1)" the problem is that this does not work for angular isolated scope with two-way binding. Solution that you propose "myArray = myArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);" doe not work either -  array in the parent scope is not modified :(

Comment: please read the documentation.  `splice` actually removes elements from the array in question.  The return value is an array of the removed elements.  No extra assignment.  Just `myArray.splice(itemIndex, 1)`

Comment: have read the docs, thanks for the pointer.  But if you read my question myArray.slice(itemIndex, 1); is exactly what I'm doing :-) The problem is that  array object is not updated e.g. item which should be removed is still there

Comment: I think this is angular specifics coupled with isolated scope and two way data binding

Comment: No `myArray.splice` with the __p__  `slice` does not remove items.  I've repeated this multiple times.  `splice` (with the __p__) does.

Comment: OMG, thank you sir!!! Could you please stress this in you answer so that other potential inattentive readers like me would be able to see the real cause of the problem. Thanks again - works like a charm ;-)

Comment: Ah no worries.  Yeah it's an easy thing to overlook.  Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution that takes advantage of one-way bindings. Two-way bindings should be avoided when you can in Angular. They're more expensive than one-way. I'm adding it because it establishes firm control of the variables involved, and it may be informative to those exploring this type of data binding. (requires at least Angular 1.5)

```
.directive('myDirective', [function(){
  return {
    scope:{
      myArray: '<',
      onArrayUpdate: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.doThings = function(){
        scope.onArrayUpdate({index_1: itemIndex, index_2: 1})
      }
    }
  }
}])

.controller('myController', ['scope',function(scope){
  scope.myArray =  [];
  scope.arraySlice = function(index_1, index_2) {
    scope.myArray = scope.myArray.slice(index_1, index_2);//or whatever your intent is
  }
}])

<my-directive my-array="myArray" on-array-slice="arraySlice(index_1, index_2)"></my-directive>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this:

`myArray.slice(itemIndex, 1);`

to this:

`myArray = myArray.slice(itemIndex, 1);`

It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this solution does not work - array in the parent scope is not modified :(

Comment: I just noticed. Use `splice(itemIndex,1)` instead of slice. It changes the original array.